# I want to do comments system with Eloquent Polymorphic Relations?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, controller, laravel-6

hi i want to build comments system in my projectDetail components 
but an error show when i try to store the comment in DB[ 1048 Column 'commentable_id' cannot be null ]
this is my ProjectDeatil.vue script :

```
  <script>
  export default {
      data(){
     return{
     key: this.$route.params.id,
projets:[],
projet:{
 id:'',
 name:'',
 durre:'',
 description:'',
 budget:'',
 owner:'',
   },
   membres:[],
    membre:{
    id :'',
    membre:'',
    projet_id:'',
},
 form : new Form({
            id:'',
            body:''

            })

     }


},

 methods:{
 afficherProjets(){
 axios.get('/api/getProjects')
  .then(({data}) => {this.projets=data.data});
 },
 afficherMembre(){
 axios.get('/api/membreid').then(({data})=> {this.membres =data.data});
 },
  ajouterCommentaire(){
  this.form.post('/api/comments/'+this.key).then(()=>{
  this.form.reset()})
  }

  },
  mounted() {
  console.log('Component mounted.')
  this.afficherProjets();
  this.afficherMembre();

  }

  }


 </script>
```

and this my CommentController function:

```
public function store($key){
     //$data =$request->all();
    $projet=new  Projet;
     $commentaire =new Commentaire;
     $commentaire->user_id= auth()->user()->id;
     $commentaire->body= request('body');
     $commentaire->commentable_id = $key;
    $projet->comments()->save($commentaire);


}
```

and this is my function in Model Comment:

```
 public function commentable(){
       return $this->morphTo();
}
```

and this my function  in Model Project:

```
public function comments(){
    return $this->morphMany('App\Commentaire','commentable')->latest();
}
```

and this is this my route:

```
 Route::post('/comments/{key}', 'API\CommentController@store');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `->save()` on polymorphic relationships in Laravel, Eloquent will magically add the correct field for you, in this case that would be `commentable_id`, so you don't need to set that if you're doing `->comments()->save()`. What you should be doing, however, is getting the `Projet` from the database and then running the code.

When you new up a `Projet` instance, Eloquent has no idea what this relates to in the database, so it's trying to save it with a `commentable_id` of `null`. Replace this line

```php
$projet=new  Projet;
```

with a line that can get the correct instance of `Projet` from the database for you, for example:

```php
$projet = Projet::find($key); // Assuming $key is the primary key of your Projet model.
```

(For the avoidance of doubt, I also recommend removing the line `$commentaire->commentable_id = $key;` too.)